# variable in javascript is not updating

Tags: javascript, variables

I intend for the below function to update the variable which will then have the result displayed in the DOM, however the variable ldead continue to show up as 0, what is the problem here?

```
cgr();
var ldead = 0
var total_customer = 0;

function cgr() {
for (var year = 0; (churn * total_customer) < (leadr * closing); year++) {
    total_customer = total_customer + (leadr * closing);
     if ((churn * total_customer) >= (leadr * closing)) {
            var ldead = year;
        }else {
    $("#car").html("something is wrong");
    };
}
```

}

the full script is here: http://pastebin.com/b0JqhTnB

Comment: Is your else statement triggering?

Comment: You might want to call `get_values()` and initialize the variables `ldead` and `total_customer` *before* you call `cgr()`?

Answer (score 1):

You are re-declaring the variable ldead where you are assigning a value to it.

Remove the "var" in front of the variable name inside the if statement, like so:

```
cgr();
var ldead = 0
var total_customer = 0;

function cgr() {
for (var year = 0; (churn * total_customer) < (leadr * closing); year++) {
    total_customer = total_customer + (leadr * closing);
     if ((churn * total_customer) >= (leadr * closing)) {
            ldead = year;
        }else {
    $("#car").html("something is wrong");
    };
}
}
```

Comment: Re-declaring, not redefining. If it was being redefined, that would be fine.

Comment: I did that but still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have used `var` inside the function so you have created a new, locally scoped variable instead of updating the one in the wider scope. Remove the `var` there.
2. You have no code to update the DOM with the new value of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

`leadr` isn't being set, and so `ldead` never gets assigned anything other than 0.